# Setting up the environment for Windows Mobile7 Application development with existing VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am interested in windows mobile7 application development and struggling with setting up the development environment. I found this [DISCUSSED LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145896/windows-phone-7-development-and-visual-studio-2010-ultimate).

(So it answered one problem that I had. I have already installed VS2010 Ultimate edition. I guess when I install Windows mobile7 SDK, it will install all the Windows mobile7 SDK tools without affecting the VS2010 that I have already Installed)

In my laptop I have windows7 64Bit operating system. Can someone please send me the steps that I should follow to make the environment to start windows mobile7 application development without affecting existing VS2010.

If someone can post the steps in sequence (including where I can find the SDK tools), Highly appreciated. Thanks inadvance...!!!

Comment: That's difficult, the last version of Windows Mobile was version 6.5.  The OS is dead, hit by a large apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Windows Phone tools without affecting existing VS2010 installation.  How would you create Phone apps without adding phone tools to the existing installation?  Adding tools is an affect, is it not?  Why worry about adding more tools?  It's not going to take anything away from VS.

Download the tools from create.msdn.com.  Run the Windows Phone tools, and start writing phone apps.  It really is that simple.  As for the tools installing the express version, I don't think so.  I have ultimate, and looking through my file system now, there is only one devenv.exe, not a second one for express.

Comment: I installed phone developer tools by the following link, http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13890. After install this when I try to Install VS2010 it says I have to Install VS2010 SP1. When I try to install VS2010 SP1 it does not install properly

Comment: SP1 is a requirement for the Phone SDK.  If there are any parts of the phone SDK installed, uninstall them, then install the SP, and finally the phone tools.  If there are no parts of the phone SDK installed, and SP1 won't install, your VS install may be borked and have to be reinstalled before you can continue.

Comment: Can you please post the steps that have to follow in the correct sequence, once we have installed visual studio 2010 Ultimate edition and need to install windows phone7 development tools. Assume visual studio 2010 SP1 is also not installed. Thank you very much. Hope this will help many people as this is so confusing.

Comment: 1. Install Visual Studio.  2. Allow updates to install SP1.  If auto update doesn't install SP1, download it from  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691  3. Run the Windows Phone 7.1 RTW SDK.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570

Comment: Hi Rich Thanks, When I try to install VS2010 SP1 I am getting an error. Don't have any idea of what. Read articles. But still can't figure out.The error is "The feature you are trying to use is on an network resource that is unavailable... Enter the alternative package 'DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi' in the box below"..

Comment: Hmmmm...  Not familiar with that, but as Dotfuscator is a Preemptive Solutions product, you may want to check with their tech support.